# Custom Dialog Window

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

i have to implement a custom dialog that should look like this and should have a special position, like i need to attach it to some component.

Could you be so kind to give me some implementation ideas?

I was thinking about overwriting the existing Android Dialog component but i am not sure i can achieve this functionality just like that.

Any link reference or idea is highly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a class which is subclass of `Dialog` class and set your custom view by `setContentView` in it, this will make your code bit cleaner. see the sample over here

[How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android/13342157#13342157)

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is create an XML exactly like you would any other layout and inflate it.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
//here is where you inflate your XML for the dialog
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_xml);

//now you can grab a reference to any component in your given xml like this
Button exampleButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.my_xml_button);

//add any listeners etc.

//display your dialog
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had a simmillar requirement , hope this helps.  ::

**CUSTOM DIALOG CLASS**

```
public class CustomDialogShape extends View {

public int startPointY,startPointX;
public int windowWidth; 
public int dialogWidth, dialogHeight;
public int leftTop, rightTop;
public CustomDialogShape(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param XPos
 * @param YPos
 * @param windowWidth
 * @param dialogHeight
 * @param dialogWidth
 * Get the Click position, dialog dimension and window width from the parent window
 * calculate the co-ordinates to draw the custom dialog shape
 */
public void setDimension(int XPos, int YPos, int windowWidth, int dialogHeight, int dialogWidth) {
    this.startPointY = YPos;
    this.startPointX = XPos;
    this.windowWidth = windowWidth;
    this.dialogHeight = dialogHeight;
    this.dialogWidth = dialogWidth;

    if(startPointX <= (windowWidth/2)) {
        //Start Position is on the left half of the Screen
        if(startPointX < (dialogWidth/2)) {
            //Start position is on the leftmost end.
            leftTop = 10;
            rightTop = leftTop + dialogWidth;
        } else {
            leftTop = startPointX - (dialogWidth/2);
            rightTop = leftTop + dialogWidth;
        }
    } else {
        int rightSideRemaining = windowWidth - startPointX;
        if(rightSideRemaining < (dialogWidth/2)) {
            //Start position is on the leftmost end.
            rightTop = windowWidth - 10;
            leftTop = rightTop - dialogWidth;
        } else {
            rightTop = startPointX + (dialogWidth/2);
            leftTop = rightTop - dialogWidth;
        }
    }


}

public CustomDialogShape(Context context, AttributeSet at) {
    super(context, at);
}


/**
 * Fill and Stroke Color
 */
@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // custom drawing code here
    // remember: y increases from top to bottom
    // x increases from left to right
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawPath(drawCustomShape(startPointX, startPointY, leftTop, rightTop), paint);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    canvas.drawPath(drawCustomShape(startPointX, startPointY, leftTop, rightTop), paint);
}


private Path drawCustomShape(int startPointX, int startPointY, int leftTop, int rightTop) {
    Path pathFill = new Path();
    pathFill.moveTo(startPointX, startPointY);
    pathFill.lineTo(startPointX - 10, startPointY + 10);
    pathFill.lineTo(leftTop, startPointY + 10);
    pathFill.lineTo(leftTop, startPointY + 10 + dialogHeight);
    pathFill.lineTo(rightTop, startPointY + 10 + dialogHeight);
    pathFill.lineTo(rightTop, startPointY + 10);
    pathFill.lineTo(startPointX + 10, startPointY + 10);
    pathFill.lineTo(startPointX, startPointY);
    pathFill.close();
    return pathFill;
}
```

**MyLAYOUT.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.cablevision.optimum2.widget.CustomDialogShape
    android:id="@+id/custom_shape"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/stb_listVals"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:divider="#AA000000"
        android:dividerHeight="7.3dip"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/login_help_thumb"
        android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/login_help_track"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**IN MY CODE**

```
                 Rect r = locateView(activity.findViewById(View_where_you_touch));


    float touchX= //get the touchx position by calculating through r.leftand r.right);              
            float touchY=r.bottom;
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Ctxt,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);                                  

        dialog.getWindow().
setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.MyLAYOUT);
            CustomDialogShape custom = (CustomDialogShape) chnSTBDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.custom_shape);
                            custom.setDimension( touchX,  touchY, custom_shape_width,
                    custom_shape_height , totalwindowWidth));                

public static Rect locateView(View view) {
    Rect loc = new Rect();
    int[] location = new int[2];
    if (view == null) {
        Logging.e(TAG, "locateView", "View not found");
}
```

In the myLAYOUT XML I had my own list, you can make change to the contents for you needs like it can be linear layouts. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a custom Dialog like follows:

```
Dialog mDialog; 

mDialog = new Dialog(YourActivityName.this);
            mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.checklist_navigatepop);//XML layout file
            mDialog.setTitle("Navigation alert");
            mDialog.setCancelable(true);
            mDialog.show();

            Button bt = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.button3);
            Button bt1 = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);

            bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();

                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your don't need extends Dialog class.

You need something like this.

```
public Dialog buildDialog() {

Dialog messageDialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);

messageDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

// Set your custom layout here.
messageDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_wifi_disabled);

// Don't let the user cancel the dialog.
messageDialog.setCancelable(false);
messageDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

// You can get the views, like this.
TextView textView = (TextView) messageDialog.findViewById(R.id.your_view);
```

}

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)